# Maxpooling 2x2 array only using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I want help in maxpooling using `numpy`.
I am learning Python for data science, here I have to do maxpooling and average pooling for `2x2` matrix, the input can be `8x8` or more but I have to do maxpool for every `2x2` matrix. I have created an matrix by using

```
k = np.random.randint(1,64,64).reshape(8,8)
```

So hereby I will be getting `8x8` matrix as a random output. Form the result I want to do `2x2` max pooling. Thanks in advance[image: i just want to perform this in numpy coding]

[image: lwhat I have done]

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I tried to split the array but didn’t worked as I expected

Comment: Can you post the code and what's happening that you don't expect? Just copy pasting a function someone gives you won't help you learn it

Comment: This is what I have executed in kaggle notebook , I don’t know how to elaborate it more, this is my assignment and I’m totally new to Python numpy

Comment: So far all we can see is creating a matrix. You say you tried to split the array hwo did oyu do it? why is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach kindly see the next answer I have posted an image !

Comment: Now I have edited, can you understand my problem ?

Comment: we understand your problem, but we don't know what you have done and what result you have got. Please not that SO is not a code writing service, at least you should show us your effort in doing something. If you are totally new to numpy, give a look at [numpy guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/)

Comment: I have added new image , that’s what I have done, and I don’t know what to do for maxpooling

Comment: What would be the resultant output of the 8x8 matrix with a 2,2 maxpooling?? 4x4?? Is that what you are expecting?

Comment: Yeah , I am expecting 4x4 as output

Comment: The right way to do this is using `np.lib.stride_tricks` which allow you to perform operations like convolutions over numpy arrays. Then once you have convolved over your matrix, you can reduce it using pooling operation. Check my answer for details.

Comment: Do test the approach below with a small hand-created matrix to see what is happening so you can confirm its behaving as you intend it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to compute the necessary strides yourself, you can just inject two auxiliary dimensions to create a 4d array that's a 2d collection of 2x2 block matrices, then take the elementwise maximum over the blocks:

```py
import numpy as np

# use 2-by-3 size to prevent some subtle indexing errors
arr = np.random.randint(1, 64, 6*4).reshape(6, 4)

m, n = arr.shape
pooled = arr.reshape(m//2, 2, n//2, 2).max((1, 3))
```

An example instance of the above:

```py
>>> arr
array([[40, 24, 61, 60],
       [ 8, 11, 27,  5],
       [17, 41,  7, 41],
       [44,  5, 47, 13],
       [31, 53, 40, 36],
       [31, 23, 39, 26]])

>>> pooled
array([[40, 61],
       [44, 47],
       [53, 40]])
```

---

For a completely general block pooling that doesn't assume 2-by-2 blocks:

```py
import numpy as np

# again use coprime dimensions for debugging safety
block_size = (2, 3)
num_blocks = (7, 5)
arr_shape = np.array(block_size) * np.array(num_blocks)
numel = arr_shape.prod()
arr = np.random.randint(1, numel, numel).reshape(arr_shape)

m, n = arr.shape  # pretend we only have this
pooled = arr.reshape(m//block_size[0], block_size[0],
                     n//block_size[1], block_size[1]).max((1, 3))
```

Comment: @ArockiaJegan I suggest avoiding `stride_tricks.as_strided` unless really necessary. It's easy to end up with garbage data. We have high-level tools like `transpose` and `reshape` to do everything safely.

Comment: when you say really necessary, do you mean when different stride or dilation is involved, like MaxPool2d in pytorch? can reshape also deal with those cases? Thanks!

Comment: @Sam-gege "really necessary" is what you can't solve with `reshape`, `transpose` or `view`. I've had one use case so far with `as_strided`, which was rendered moot with https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html

Comment: And I don't know pytorch. But looking at https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic/blob/master/README.md (linked from pytorch docs): seems like padding is not a problem, but indeed arbitrary strides might be problematic. I'd probably go for this approach (when applicable) or `sliding_window_view` (but skipping windows as required by strides).

Comment: Thanks Andras. looks like `sliding_window_view` is easier. I've had some hard time in the beginning experimenting `as_strided`, often ended up in garbage data lol. BTW, I've got another similar question regarding max pooling, are you interested to have a look?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69423484/python-numpy-get-indices-of-element-of-one-array-using-indices-in-another-array

Comment: @Sam-gege not just easier: safer. You can't get garbage data with `sliding_window_view`, which is the main point. (Thanks for the link, answered it.)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the convolution part using `np.lib.stride_tricks` which is actually how the numpy generates views from its methods in the background. Be careful though, this is memory level access to numpy arrays.

1. Convolve over the (8,8) matrix to get (4,4) matrices of (2,2) shape.
2. Reduce the (2,2) matrics with a pooling operation such as mean to get a (4,4) output.

This approach is scalable to larger matrices without any modification and can accommodate larger convolutions as well.

```
k = np.random.randint(1,64,64).reshape(8,8)

#Strides
x,y = 2,2

shape = k.shape[0]//x, k.shape[1]//y, x, y  
strides = k.strides[0]*x, k.strides[1]*y, k.strides[0], k.strides[1]

print('expected shape:',shape)
print('required strides:',strides)

convolve = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(k, shape=shape, strides=strides)
print('convolution output shape:',convolve.shape)

maxpool = np.mean(convolve, axis=(-1,-2))
print('maxpooled output shape:',maxpool.shape)


print(' ')
print('Input matrix:')
print(k)
print('--------')
print('Output matrix:')
print(maxpool)
```

```
expected shape: (4, 4, 2, 2)
required strides: (128, 16, 64, 8)
convolution output shape: (4, 4, 2, 2)
maxpooled output shape: (4, 4)
 
Input matrix:
[[19 32 28 25 31 49 17 18]
 [ 4 19 50 57 29 42  5  8]
 [44 16 54 13 15  1 58 50]
 [18 36 29 12 39 45 47 44]
 [34 31 17 28 35 62 30 54]
 [38 50 14 50 25 24 36  4]
 [58 27 20 34 55 22 63 59]
 [61 30 37 24 23 34  5 16]]
--------
Output matrix:
[[18.5  40.   37.75 12.  ]
 [28.5  27.   25.   49.75]
 [38.25 27.25 36.5  31.  ]
 [44.   28.75 33.5  35.75]]
```

Just to confirm, if you take just the first (2,2) window of your matrix and apply mean pooling on it, you get 18.5 which is the first value of your output matrix, as expected.

```
first_window = [[19,32],
                 [4,19]]

np.mean(first_window)

# 18.5
```

---

## EXPLANATION

Numpy stores its ndarrays as contiguous blocks of memory. Each element is stored in a sequential manner every n bytes after the previous.

So if your 3D array looks like this  -

```
np.arange(0,16).reshape(2,2,4)

#array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],
#
#       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15]]])
```

[image]

Then in memory its stores as -

[image]

When retrieving an element (or a block of elements), NumPy calculates how many `strides` (of 8 bytes each) it needs to traverse to get the next element `in that direction/axis`. So, for the above example, for `axis=2` it has to traverse 8 bytes (depending on the `datatype`) but for `axis=1` it has to traverse `8*4` bytes, and `axis=0` it needs `8*8` bytes.

This is where `arr.strides` comes in. It shows the number of bytes required to access the next element in that direction.

For your case with the (8,8) matrix -

1. You want to convolve the 8x8 matrix by a (2,2) step in each direction, therefore resulting in a (4,4,2,2) shaped matrix. Then you want to reduce the last 2 dimensions in your maxpooling step with an average resulting in a (4,4) matrix.
2. The `shape` is what you define as your expected shape which is (4,4,2,2) in this case
3. The convolution needs to access memory however by take 2 steps in each direction (k.strides[0]*2 = 128 bytes and k.strides[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRMEA.png)*2 = 16 bytes to get the first element of the (2,2) window, then for another (64,8) bytes.

> NOTE: The try to NEVER hardcode the strides/shapes in this function. Can result in memory issue. Always use calculate the expected strides and shape from the strides and shapes of the original matrix.

Hope this helps. Read more about stride_tricks [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/advanced-numpy-master-stride-tricks-with-25-illustrated-exercises-923a9393ab20).

Comment: Ammazing , just awesome, but I have to learn about strides and others, anyway thanks man

Comment: Definitely do. If you want to master numpy, stride_tricks is absolutely essential since it allows you to work with arrays at memory level and do anything you want with them. Its insanely powerful and is the actual method that majority of the functions in numpy actually use in their background.

Comment: Check the last link that I have linked in my answer. its a great tutorial of 25 examples to use, understand and master stride tricks over numpy arrays.. including stuff like accessing values in zig zag way or a simple transpose.