# python numpy maxpool: given an array and indices from argmax, returns max values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, max-pooling

suppose I have an array called `view`:

```
array([[[[ 7,  9],
         [10, 11]],

        [[19, 18],
         [20, 16]]],


       [[[24,  5],
         [ 6, 10]],

        [[18, 11],
         [45, 12]]]])
```

as you may know from maxpooling, this is a view of the original input, and the kernel size is 2x2:

```
[[ 7,  9],  [[19, 18],
 [10, 11]],  [20, 16]]], ....
```

The goal is to find both max values and their indices. However, `argmax` only works on single axis, so I need to **flatten** `view`, i.e. using `flatten=view.reshape(2,2,4)`:

```
array([[[ 7,  9, 10, 11], [19, 18, 20, 16]],

       [[24,  5,  6, 10], [18, 11, 45, 12]]])
```

Now, with the help I get from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69423484/get-indices-of-element-of-one-array-using-indices-in-another-array), I can find indices of max using `inds = flatten.argmax(-1)`:

```
array([[3, 2],
       [0, 2]])
```

and values of max:

```
i, j = np.indices(flatten.shape[:-1])
flatten[i, j, inds]

>>> array([[11, 20],
           [24, 45]])
```

**The problem**
the problem arise when I **flatten** the `view` array. Since `view` array is a view of the original array i.e. `view = as_strided(original, newshape, newstrides)`, so `view` and `original` shares the same data. However, `reshape` breaks it, so any change on `view` is not reflected on `original`. This is problematical during backpropagation.

**My question**
Given the array `view` and indices `ind`, I'd like to change max values in `view` to 1000, without using reshape, or any operation that breaks the 'bond' between `view` and `original`. Thanks for any help!!!

**reproducible example**

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

original=np.array([[[7,9,19,18],[10,11,20,16]],[[24,5,18,11],[6,10,45,12]]],dtype=np.float64)
view=as_strided(original, shape=(2,1,2,2,2),strides=(64,32*2,8*2,32,8))
```

I'd like to change max values of each kernel in `view` to, say, 1000, that can be reflected on `original`, i.e. if I run `view[0,0,0,0,0]=1000`, then the first element of both view and original are 1000.

Comment: You can aid the people trying to answer your question by preparing a runnable [mcve]: an array, a view, and then what you want to do with it.

Comment: Hi Andras I've added an example :)

Comment: And as you can see it worked :P Yet again you don't need (and should not use) `as_strided`: `view = original.reshape(2, 1, 2, 2, 2).transpose(0, 1, 3, 2, 4)`.

Comment: yep you are right. although sometimes when stride, dilation and groups are involved, like in pytorch conv2d, I don't know if there are any other options for me. I've just finished writing this maxpooling using numpy, can't believe it's harder than a conv2d, indexing has given me so much headaches smh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

```
import numpy as np
view = np.array(
    [[[[ 7,  9],
       [10, 11]],
      [[19, 18],
       [20, 16]]],
     [[[24,  5],
       [ 6, 10]],
      [[18, 11],
       [45, 12]]]]
)
# Getting the indices of the max values
max0 = view.max(-2)
idx2 = view.argmax(-2)
idx2 = idx2.reshape(-1, idx2.shape[1])
max1 = max0.max(-1)
idx3 = max0.argmax(-1).flatten()
idx2 = idx2[np.arange(idx3.size), idx3]

idx0 = np.arange(view.shape[0]).repeat(view.shape[1])
idx1 = np.arange(view.shape[1]).reshape(1, -1).repeat(view.shape[0], 0).flatten()

# Replacing the maximal vlues with 1000
view[idx0, idx1, idx2, idx3] = 1000
print(f'view = \n{view}')
```

output:

```
view = 
[[[[   7    9]
   [  10 1000]]

  [[  19   18]
   [1000   16]]]


 [[[1000    5]
   [   6   10]]

  [[  18   11]
   [1000   12]]]]
```

Basically, idx{n} is the index of the maximal value in the last two dimensions for every matrix contained in the first two dimensions.

Comment: Thanks Yann this looks promising! could you please adapt your answer a bit based on my `original` and `view` from reproducible example?

Comment: @Sam-gege. woudl you kindly adapt your reproducible example to include a single, clear  tuple of inputs as well as a clear and full expected output? as it stands, i don't understand what is the input or what is wrong with the output in my answer.

Comment: Hi Yann, the input is just  my `view` array from reproducible example section, which is one more dimension than your `view`. But anyways, I've made the necessary changes. you just need to change this `idx2 = idx2.reshape(-1, idx2.shape[ - 1])` i.e. idx2.shape(-1) rather than shape(1). Other than that, there should be 3 axis in `view[ i, j, k, idx2, idx3] = 1000`, where `i,j,k=np.indices(view.shape[:-2])` to save some work. anyways, I've accept your answer, thanks man!