# Why is 4D realisation of Max-Pooling in numpy misleading?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, conv-neural-network, max-pooling

I'm trying to understand an algorithm of Max-Pooling in numpy. There are many answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69325207/3044825) that offer to give a new 4 - dimensional shape to two - dimensional image and then call `np.max` on axis 1 and 3:

```
window = (2, 4)
arr = np.random.randint(99, size=(1,8,12))
shape = (arr.shape[1]//window[0], window[0], arr.shape[2]//window[1], window[1])
out = arr.reshape(shape).max(axis=(1, 3))
```

According to my visual understanding, I should operate on `axis=(0, 2)` so it will shrink to the size 1 and produce an output like so:

[image]

That makes a lot of sense but it's not correct:

```
arr = np.random.randint(99, size=(1,8,12)) =
[[[ 7 55 21 88 69 35  7  7 73 54 16 80]
  [70 79 62 55 42  5 77 81 38 52 69 39]
  [58 78 48 35  5 93 47 64 18 25 73 25]
  [14  8 63 27 28 46 29 68 28 38 51 79]
  [70 15 37 51 72 27 44 79  1 79 75  9]
  [ 4 27  0 90 15 30 95 62 14  8 69 57]
  [24 29 26 44 72 89 74 78 39 29  6  2]
  [82 12  0 11 54 38 61 79 91 92 53 28]]]
--------------------------------------------------
arr.reshape(4, 2, 3, 4).max(axis=(0, 2)) =
[[73 93 75 88]
 [91 92 95 90]]
--------------------------------------------------
arr.reshape(4, 2, 3, 4).max(axis=(1, 3)) =
[[88 81 80]
 [78 93 79]
 [90 95 79]
 [82 89 92]]
```

So it doesn't ever agree with my picture in reality. What is the source of this disagreement? What are the reasons it's not working as expected?

Comment: `np.random.randn(2,4).max(0)` produces the maximum for every row of the table-like array i.e. shape of the resulting array corresponds to the remaining axes. Therefore, doing max over axis 0 and 2 will give you array of shape window (sorry if I misunderstood the question)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. `max(axis)` means that you pool along `axis`. Here, you want to pool `axis=(1,3)` to one scalar (max value) as they are your window size. `axis=(0,2)` should stay intact.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand your confusion now.  The second picture is incorrect, `axis=1` should be your `window[0]`, which is `2`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Good point! The lengths of axes don't seem to be consistent with diagram on Fig. 2. How do I fix it? Do I need to build a cuboid in a different way or just to replace axis of existing one?

Comment: Just rename the axis is good. Then you would see that it makes sense.